# Shell script to create loop for command

Tags: shell, unix, tcl, ns2

So i have a tcl code that i need to run in ns2. As we all know i just have to type 'ns abc.tcl' in terminal. In my abc.tcl code i have a variable x which i need to change and run the code. Is there any way i can write a script that will change the value of x and run 'ns abc.tcl' in terminal, then change the value again and run 'ns abc.tcl' in terminal again for a set of values for x. I believe i need to write a shell script but i don't know anything about that. Can you tell me the format i should write the script in like what should i write first and where do i write my values of x and how to make it run 'ns abc.tcl in terminal: 'function()' 'do' 'done' etc... If you can direct me to specific links about that would be helpful.

Comment: You write a script in `bash` to feed a variable in your `tcl` code? Why can can't just pass in command-line and process it inside `tcl`?

Comment: Actually my tcl code generate an integer(throughput) as result. There is a wide range of values for x so its tiresome to change it by myself and run it everytime. I tried to write a for loop enclosing the entire tcl code but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, providing it works, is to pass the value in as an argument.

1. Invoke your code as `ns abc.tcl TheValueToPassIn`.
2. Access the value within your code by indexing into the `argv` global variable with `lindex`, which should contain a list of all arguments after the script name:

   ```
   set myValue [lindex $::argv 0]
   ```

However, it's possible that that won't work (depending on *exactly* what the `ns` program does). If so, pass the value in inside an environment variable:

1. Invoke your code as `MYVAR=TheValueToPassIn ns abc.tcl`.
2. Access the value within your code by looking in the global `env` array:

   ```
   set myValue $::env(MYVAR)
   ```

There are many other ways to do it, but those two are very easy.